# How is epinephrine and norepinephrine different?

Tags: human-physiology

Is there any difference between epinephrine and norepinephrine?

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-epinephrine-and-norepinephrine

This site says that norepinephrine is also a neurotransmitter.

Is there any major difference between them?

Comment: Epinephrine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine

Norepinephrine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine

Comment: Please can you list the major differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But little amount of epinephrine also serve as a neurotransmitter.

Iam mentioning here some of the differences I found out myself when I had the same question.

If you need further reading you can visit the site  as mentioned by @Spartacus9
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine

1)Norepinephrine is mostly made inside nerve axons and released when an action potential travels down the nerve.

Epinephrine is made from norepinephrine inside the adrenal medulla.

2)Norepinephrine acts mostly on alpha receptors.

Epinephrine is relatively non specific,stimulating both alpha,beta1,beta2,beta3 receptors more or less equally.

3)In medicine, norepinephrine is used to increase and maintain blood pressure related to cardiac arrest,spinal anaesthesia,septicaemia,etc.

Epinephrine is used in medicine to treat low blood pressure associated with septic shock and also for the emergency treatment of allergic reactions.